# Center #Div after Drag or Drop with Jquery UI (fiddle inside)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, resize, draggable

I would love to center a div always after drag or drop.

Here is my fiddle for forking
http://jsfiddle.net/vrUgs/895/

Here my js:

```
     $(function() {
    $("#resizable").draggable({
    stop: function(event, ui) 
           {
               $("#resizable").css({
                   'display':'block',
                  'margin':'auto'
               });
           }
    });
    $("#resizable").resizable({
    stop: function(event, ui) 
           {
               $("#resizable").css({
                   'display':'block',
                  'margin':'auto'
               });     
alert("left="+ui.position.left+",width="+ui.size.width);
           }
    });  
    });
```

Question 1: How to make it center after each drag and drop and alert than the centered position?

Question 2: Can my code be simplified ... since i use the same stop function for drag/drop?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: but if you center it, it will just be movable upwards and downwards

Comment: yeah i know. in production environment i would only use it with resizable since with dragable it would be obsolet. i have reason for doing this.

Comment: well, since some time passed, where you able to fix your problem?

Comment: No. its not near crossbrowser comptability and the "left:0" mess up all additional div's. it's a hack - i need a solid solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#resizable").css({
    'display':'block',
    'margin':'auto',
    'left':'0'
});
```

would do the centering part

see: http://jsfiddle.net/t9rFu/

and for resizing:

```
$("#resizable").css({
    'display':'block',
    'margin':'auto',
    'left':'0',
    'position':'relative'
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t9rFu/1/

Comment: that doesn't work. try to resize and after that it will snap to left and not center.

Comment: yea, jquery obviously sets position to absolute on resize, edited my answer

Comment: the display and margin css in the jquery code are obsolete tough